# C++ Passing pointer in singleton-Then program has stopped working?

Tags: c++, pointers, singleton

So I tried to develop a class Scoreboard and a class Player and a class Player2(All singleton) and each play should possess a pointer to this Scoreboard. When I run my program it stopped working and I believe it is because of the pointer because it occurs when I tried to access the Scoreboard that the Player point at. So the basic idea is :
(header.h)

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    class Scoreboard
    {
    private:
        static Scoreboard *instance;
    Scoreboard()
    {
        p1=0;
        p2=0;
        num=0;
        board[0]="a";       
    };
    public :
    int p1;
    int p2;
    int num;
    string board[9];
    static Scoreboard *startGame()
    {
        if (NULL==instance)
        {
        instance = new Scoreboard();
        }
        return instance ;
    };  
    void printScore()
    {
        cout<<"X "<<p1<<endl;
        cout<<"O "<<p2<<endl;
    }
    void makeMove(string move)
    {
        cout<<move<<endl;
        cout<<p1<<endl;
        board[num]=move;
        cout<<"(plays"<<move<<")"<<endl;
        num++;
    }

    };
    Scoreboard* Scoreboard::instance=NULL;
    class Player
    {
    private :
    static Player *instance;
    Player(char n2,string f2,Scoreboard *sb2)
    {
        name=n2;
        fileName=f2;
        op.open(fileName.c_str());
        s=sb2;
    }
    public:
    string fileName;
    char name;
    string move;
    ifstream op;
    Scoreboard *s;
    static Player *ins(char n,string f,Scoreboard *sb)
    {
        if (NULL==instance)
        {
            instance=new Player(n,f,sb);
        }
        return instance;
    }
    int makeMove()
    {
        cout<<name<<"'s move"<<endl;
        if (!op.eof())
        {
            if (op.is_open())
            {
                cout<<"successfully opened"<<endl;
            }
        op>>move;
        cout<<"successfully got value"<<endl;
        s->makeMove(move);
        return 1;
        }else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    };
    Player* Player::instance=NULL;




    class Player2
    {
    private :
    static Player2 *instance2;
    Player2(char n2,string f2,Scoreboard *sb2)
    {
        name=n2;
        fileName=f2;
        op.open(fileName.c_str());
        s=sb2;
    }
    public:
    string fileName;
    char name;
    string move;
    ifstream op;
    Scoreboard *s;

    static Player2 *ins(char n,string f,Scoreboard *sb)
    {
        if (NULL==instance2)
        {
            instance2=new Player2(n,f,sb);
        }
        return instance2;
    }
    int makeMove()
    {
        cout<<name<<"'s move"<<endl;
        if (!op.eof())
        {
            if (op.is_open())
            {
                cout<<"successfully opened"<<endl;
            }
        op>>move;
        cout<<"successfully got value"<<endl;

        s->makeMove(move);

        return 1;
        }else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    };
    Player2* Player2::instance2=NULL;
```

and .cpp would be:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "header.h"

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
    string store;
    string temp;
    string temp2;
    getline(cin,store);
    istringstream stm(store);
    stm>>temp;
    Scoreboard* si=NULL;
    Player* ply1=NULL;
    Player2* ply2=NULL;

    if (temp=="game")
    {
        Scoreboard* si= Scoreboard::startGame();
        cout<<si->p1<<endl;
        cout<<si->p2<<endl;
        cout<<si->board[0]<<endl;


    }
    stm>>temp;
    stm>>temp2;

    if (temp=="stdin"&&temp2=="stdin")
    {

    }else
    {
        ply1=Player::ins('X',temp,si);
        ply2=Player2::ins('O',temp2,si);
        cout<<ply1->s->p1<<endl;
    -----------------------------------------------------
     //This is where program stop working(I think)
    -----------------------------------------------------


    }

    while(1)
    {
        ply1->makeMove();
        ply2->makeMove();
    }
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        cout<<si->board[i]<<" ";
    }

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: You may also consider that Singleton is considered to be a bad practice or an anti-pattern. It is not much better than a global variable, and this has been known to be problematic for decades. It is better to not get used to this bad habbit early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue I see is this:

```
 if (temp=="game")
 {
   Scoreboard* si= Scoreboard::startGame();`  
   //...
 }
```

`si` is a local variable, so outside the `}`, it no longer exists.  That `si` above is not the same as the `si` you declared earlier in `main`:

`Scoreboard* si=NULL;`

Thus you are dereferencing a NULL pointer here, as the "real" `si` is never set:

`cout<<si->board[i]<<" ";`

Comment: OH THANKS! This has bothered me for 2 days...lol